# How to graph a number line with writings on top?

Tags: tikz-pgf

here is the image which i want to put in LaTeX.

[image: number line]

I want to be able to draw the portion in yellow with tikz.

Please help.
Here's the MWE, which is not at all okay:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=none,
            height=50pt,
            width=\axisdefaultwidth,
            xmin=-10,
            xmax=10,
            ]
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (5,0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you tray so far?

Comment: I'v edited my question to include MWE, but it is no where near to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your MWE is not complete nor even close to desired image. You need to make yourself more familiar with `tikz` and `pgfplots`. Try to read their documentation (ad list inztroductionary chapters and sections), also see [TeXample](https://texample.net/) and [pgfplots examples](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/all/?page=4).
- for this image is simpler to use `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.14159]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[Straight Barb-Straight Barb]
    (0,0) to ["$x=-1$"] ++ (3,0) coordinate (a) 
          to ["$x=1$"]  ++ (2,0) coordinate (b)
          to ["$x=6$"]  ++ (3,0);
\foreach \x in {a,b}
    \draw (a) ++ (0,1mm) -- ++ (0,-2mm)  node[below] {0}
          (b) ++ (0,1mm) -- ++ (0,-2mm)  node[below] {5};          
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, meaning/intention of this image is quite unclear ...

Comment: thanks, with a little tweaking, it worked.
This is actually a part of a solution of an quadratic inequality where you find the solutions and test several points in the interval to see which interval is the solution.